# Using JSON Schema, how do I validate an object where keys and values are not known in advance?

Tags: jsonschema

i need to validate this format:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "team": "red",
        "L3_HCU_TESTS": "N",
        "dbo_user": "user",
        "version": 920
    }
}
```

I don't know in advance names of keys and values.

"variables" are not mandatory but if it's provided,
keys can be any string, and value can be any value.
What is important for me is to validate that "variables" (if provider) will include key and value.
Empty values are not allowed

Comment: Have a look at `additionalProperties` here: http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html

Comment: thank you for replay, i read a link and can't find my implementation. In my case key and value of dict are unknown like --> "variables": { "unknown-key1": "unknown-value1", "unknown-key2": "unknown-value1" }, and values that be anything

Answer (score 0):

With a JSON Object, the keys MUST be a string, so your requirement for string based keys is already covered by "is valid JSON".

Expanding your requirements, you want:

- "variables" must be an object
- There must be at least one property in the object
- The value of the properties must not be null

Here's a schema which satisfies those requirements:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "variables": {
      "type": "object",
      "minProperties": 1,
      "additionalProperties": {
        "not": {
          "type": "null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can test it against your instance [using this link](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVNX4tqufhQCWuMCURwkyMgDdC-Y4QBGAGzMWrNm6goBPAwtUFmdGXEwKDS1vMnxjeAAFPQMjU3MoRABGTWtvVEIREWMTNkJXJP1DEw8MrxjtEHgWSNro+ob-QIzUeABXV1dUNpiAX2HkMdzESYmEEZB1EGMoGGjUe0cXd3TSOo7cQnwgkH5cESip1AAZAGYAfQAJAGEAVTuAFQBRAGV37+OAHIXPIgETOFh3XpgQzHKEwhbDdaGMDGNgWACcACYZNFJvMRkA).

`"type": "object"` makes sure that "variables" is an object.

`"minProperties"` makes sure there is a minimum number of properties in an object.

`"additionalProperties"` value subschema is applied to all key values in the object (as "properties" and "patternProperties" are not defined). The subschema inverts the result of a subschema, which defines the type must be null. The inversion results in, must be NOT NULL.

I haven't seen `minProperties` used very often. Here's the reference link for that JSON Schema keyword: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.2